# Shopping Cart modal when adding a new item - rails 5 jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I want a shopping cart to show up as a modal when a user add an item to it. The 'add to cart' button is on the products#show view page, inside a form_tag that posts to order_items#create controller in order to create a new item in a shopping Cart. I get confused because what I want is a show of the cart, but I guess I don't want to call my Cart controller, just call the view of it from the order_item create action.
I added a create.js.erb in my views/order_items folder, and a partial in the layout folder. What I get is this error : ActionController::UnknownFormat (OrderItemsController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.
I can't know how to make rails find the right template. Anyone could help?

Products#show

```
        <%= form_tag order_items_path  class: "coffee_form", remote: true do %>

        <%= select_tag "grind", raw("#{raw_str}"), multiple: false, class:"coffee_form btn-block form-control-lg"  %>


        <%= label_tag Product.human_attribute_name("weight")%>
        <%= select_tag "weight", raw("<option>250</option><option>1000</option>"), multiple: false, class:"coffee_form btn-block form-control-lg", id:"selected_weight", onchange: "displayPrice();"  %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'product_id', @product.id %>
          <div class='mt-3'>
            <%= submit_tag t("addcart"), class: 'btn btn-block btn-warning', data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#myModal'} %>
```

OrderItems#create

```
 def create
   chosen_weight = params[:weight].to_i
   chosen_product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
....
      @order_item = OrderItem.new
....

      if session[:cart_id] == nil
          @current_cart = Cart.create
          session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
      end


      @order_item.cart_id = @current_cart.id
      @order_item.product = @product
      @order_item.grind = params[:grind]
      @order_item.quantity = params[:quantity]
      @order_item.shipping_points = @product.shipping_points * params[:quantity].to_i


     @order_item.save!

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # create.html.erb
        format.js # create.js.erb

    end
```

create.js.erb in views/order_items folder

```
$('myModal').html('<%= j render "layouts/modal"');
```

_modal.html.erb in views/layouts folder

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing. Here `$('myModal').html('<%= j render "layouts/modal"');` you have not closed your Rails tag. Regarding your problem do you have more context ? Can you see an XHR call in the browser ? As you pass your form as `remote: true` and have both HTML and JS template it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want, from the `order_items#create` action, to redirect to the `carts#show`, but ensure you render with no layout.

Then, when you use `fetch` to post the new order item, get the rendered content and put it in your modal/popover/other.

If you use turbo, you can make it happen automatically by just rendering the modal in a turbo-frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rewritten. Previously I had a :
redirect_to cart_path(current_cart) in my orderItems#create controller. How do I render it with no layout? Either, I am not sure how to use 'fetch'. Do you mean, in the create controller?